# Can anyone translate this slang heavy Chilean Spanish meme? (Possibly NSFW for all I know)

Tags: chile

[**Here's the meme**](https://streamable.com/lqpq6e)

I initially tried google translate, then on to googling the individual words which didn't get me anywhere, so I now have to resort to begging online. Does anyone mind translating this meme?

Comment: Hello, user, note that we usually do not accept plain translations of Spanish texts to other languages. But we can help if there are any specific words you don't understand and need help with. It could be interesting to make a wiki answer with the meaning of heavy Spanish slang words (and insults).

Comment: At the risk of sounding ignorant, what is NSFW?

Comment: @cuevero [Not safe for work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work). Includes all kinds of content that you would not like to be seen watching in a public, formal environment, such as sexuality, profanity, violence...

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's help on a few of the words or spellings that online translators probably won't help with (though I'm not super confident on some of the slang), and I'll also note that the accents were generally left off (e.g. *calmate* was written in the video even though *cálmate* was spoken/meant), so that might affect automatic translators:

- *oe*: pretty sure this is *oye* ("hey")
- *aweonado*: See [this q&a](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4801) for further discussion on *weón*, but I think "stupid" might work as a translation here
- *eri*: *erí* or *erís* (though my ears generally never heard the "s" sound, but Chileans sometimes claimed to me they can distinguish between things like *gracias* y *gracia* where my ears heard no difference), a 2nd-person singular of *ser* in a conjugation particular to Chilean Spanish (other regions would use *eres* or *sos*), [learn more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilean_Spanish#Pronouns_and_verbs), so this would mean "you are" / "you're".
- *maraco*: I think would probably be "faggot" (at least as translated to US English)
- *ui*: I'm guessing this is what I'd generally see spelled as *uy* or *huy*, an interjection something like "ay", "ow", "whoa", "yikes"
- *conchetumadre*: very common Chilean vulgar slang, literally (in a more pendantic spelling) *concha de tu madre* but some sounds get left out (in fact it's sometimes abbreviated *CTM*), I'd go with "motherfucker" as a kind of default translation
- *culiao*: A literal spelling (*culeado*) or translation ("fucked in the ass") would not reflect these guys' usage/meaning, but from [this page](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/Culiao) and [this page](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-meaning-of-culiao-in-Spanish?share=1), I'd say "fucker" would probably be a decent translation.
- *po*: (here included in *si po* where that *si* should be written *sí*) is a shortened form of the word *pues* (though shortened to that form [seemingly only in Chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/po-for-pues-anywhere-else-but-chile)), which is a kind of "filler word", so a bit difficult to translate, or the translation will vary by context, but is very common in Chile added after *sí*/*no*/*ya* (in fact their most popular buying/selling online platform is called Yapo).
- *weon*: see link above about *weón*, but I feel like this is used in Chile in ways I would hear used "dude" in English
- *sies*: that isn't Chilean, just a bad spelling of *si es* ("if it's")
- *cabros*: *cabro/a* is used in Chile to refer to kids / young people, I would translate his usage here as "guys".

Hope this helps. Glad to receive corrections from those more versed in the nuances of these Chilenismos.